# python pandas rolling window and recreate data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'],
                  'attritube1' : [0,1,1,1,0,2,9], 
                  'attritube2':[1,2,3,3,0,0,1]})
print(df)

     attritube1  attritube2 user
0           0           1    A
1           1           2    A
2           1           3    A
3           1           3    B
4           0           0    B
5           2           0    B
6           9           1    B
```

I would like to slice the data with a rolling window of length K **for every user** and create a new data set. For example, if K = 2, then I would like to get

```
   attritube1  attritube2 user
0           0           1    A
1           1           2    A
---------------------------------
2           1           2    A
3           1           3    A
---------------------------------
4           1           3    B
5           0           0    B
---------------------------------
6           0           0    B
7           2           0    B
--------------------------------
8           2           0    B
9           9           1    B
```

Similarly, if K = 3, then the new data frame should be

```
    attritube1  attritube2 user
0           0           1    A
1           1           2    A
2           1           3    A
--------------------------------
3           1           3    B
4           0           0    B
5           2           0    B
--------------------------------
6           0           0    B
7           2           0    B
8           9           1    B
```

We can assume that for all users, the number of rows >= K. Thanks!

Edit: Want to clarify that I want to repeat the rolling window procedure for every user (A,B in the toy example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
k=3
pd.concat([df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x.iloc[i: i + k] for i in range(len(x.index) - k + 1)]))])


        attribute1  attribute2 user
user                               
A    0           0           1    A
     1           1           2    A
     2           1           3    A
B    3           1           3    B
     4           0           0    B
     5           2           0    B
     4           0           0    B
     5           2           0    B
     6           9           1    B
```

Comment: I want to clarify that I want to repeat the rolling window procedure for every user (see "user" column). Sorry if it wasn't clear in my original post.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your help! But the output is different from the sample output for k = 3 which is shown in the posting.

Comment: see update, I think the new version gives you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'user' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','B','A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'],
              'attritube1' : [0,1,1,1,0,2,9,0,1,1,1,0,2,9,0,1,1,1,0,2,9], 
              'attritube2':[1,2,3,3,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,2,9,0,1,1,1,0,2,9]})


 # creating Multi Index Data Frame
 m_df=df.set_index(df["user"],append=True)
 m_df=m_df.swaplevel(0,1,axis=0)


 k=2


 final_df=pd.concat([m_df.loc[item].iloc[:k] for item in sorted(set(df["user"]))])
 final_df.index=range(final_df.shape[0])  # to resort the index 


print final_df
```

This answer used Multi Index Data Frame and does it step by step, which (at least for me) is a little easier to read.

Comment: I want to clarify that I want to repeat the rolling window procedure for every user (see "user" column). Sorry if it wasn't clear in my original post.